# Regular Expression to find each word of a string excluding those between delimiters

Tags: c#, regex

There are many articles about finding words between two delimiters, but in my case, I want to exclude words between delimiters and keep the others. Simple examples should be helpful:

First example: [Hi!]My name is John.
It should return 4 matches: "My" "name" "is" "John."

Second example: My name is John [I suppose].
It should return 5 matches: "My" "name" "is" "John" "."

Is it possible to do something like this with a regular expression?
Many thanks.

[edit] I'm using a C# application that allows me as a user to provide my own regular expression to customize the way it counts words, but I cannot change the code itself.

Comment: From your examples, the bracketed area isn't a delimeter, it's just something you want to strip out.

Comment: You can process the string to remove the parts inside `[]`, then match the rest.

Comment: @nhahtdh Unfortunately, in my case, I can not do a preprocessing on the text but for those who can, this effectively would simplify the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\[[^\]]*\]|(\S+)
```

Try this.Grab the capture.See demo.Here we match `[]` first and then capture the rest and make a group of it.

https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/33

or

```
([^\[\]\s]+)(?![^\[]*\])
```

See demo.This makes sure the characters that match should not have a `]` in front of them without `[`.So this in essence captures the characters not inside `[]`.

https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/34

Comment: No explanation at all?